# LeetCode 639: Decode Ways II

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem copied here. If you would like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

> A message containing letters from A-Z is being encoded to numbers
> using the following mapping way:
>
> ```
> 'A' -> 1 
> 'B' -> 2 
> ... 
> 'Z' -> 26
> ```
>
> Beyond that, now the encoded string can also contain the character
> '*', which can be treated as one of the numbers from 1 to 9.
>
> Given the encoded message containing digits and the character '*',
> return the total number of ways to decode it.
>
> Also, since the answer may be very large, you should return the output
> mod \$10^9 + 7\$.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> - Input: "*"
> - Output: 9
> - Explanation: The encoded message can be decoded to the string: "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I".
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> - Input: "1*"
> - Output: 9 + 9 = 18
>
> #### Example 3:
>
> - Input: "2*"
> - Output: 15
>
> #### Example 4:
>
> - Input: "3*"
> - Output: 9
>
> #### Example 5:
>
> - Input: "44*4"
> - Output: 11
>
> #### Note:
>
> - The length of the input string will fit in range [1, 105].
> - The input string will only contain the character '*' and digits '0' - '9'.

#### Code

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Solution {
    static constexpr size_t MOD = 1e9 + 7;
public:
    static size_t numDecodings(const std::string message);
    static size_t decode(const char a_num_ast);
    static size_t decode(const char a_num_ast, const char b_num_ast);
};

inline size_t Solution::decode(const char a_num_ast) {
    if (a_num_ast == '*') {
        return 9;

    } else if (a_num_ast == '0') {
        return 0;

    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

inline size_t Solution::decode(const char a_num_ast, const char b_num_ast) {
    if (a_num_ast == '1') {
        if (b_num_ast == '*') {
            return 9;

        } else if (b_num_ast >= '0' && b_num_ast <= '9') {
            return 1;
        }

    } else if (a_num_ast == '2') {
        if (b_num_ast == '*') {
            return 6;

        } else if (b_num_ast >= '0' && b_num_ast <= '6') {
            return 1;
        }

    } else if (a_num_ast == '0') {
        return 0;

    } else if (a_num_ast == '*') {
        return decode('1', b_num_ast) + decode('2',  b_num_ast);
    }

    return 0;
}

inline size_t Solution::numDecodings(const std::string message) {
    const size_t length = message.size();
    std::vector<size_t> decodes_dp(3, 0);
    decodes_dp[0] = 1;
    decodes_dp[1] = decode(message[0]);

    for (size_t index = 2; index <= length; index++) {
        decodes_dp[index % 3] = (decodes_dp[(index - 1) % 3] * decode(message[index - 1]) % MOD +
                                 decodes_dp[(index - 2) % 3] * decode(message[index - 2], message[index - 1]) % MOD) % MOD;
    }

    return decodes_dp[length % 3];
}
```

#### References

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-ways-ii/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-ways-ii/solution/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-ways-ii/discuss/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Make helper functions `private`

Member functions that are not part of the public API should be marked `private`.
You should know that by now :)

## Use `uint64_t` instead of `size_t`

There is no guarantee that `size_t` is big enough for the calculations you are doing. While you might only need 32 bits to store the results, you need to do the calculations using 64 bit integers (because you are multiplying two numbers that are each up to 30 bits in size). So to be safe, I would use `uint64_t`. You could use `uint32_t` as well, but then you need to explicitly cast to `uint64_t` before doing the multiplications inside `numDecodings()`.

Use `size_t` for sizes and counts, but not for other purposes.

## Make the `decode()` functions `constexpr`

I see you made `MOD` `constexpr`, which is great, but you can make the `decode()` functions `constepxr` as well.

## Naming things

`a_num_ast` and `b_num_ast` are weird looking names. I'm guessing by `a_num_ast` you mean "**a** variable that can hold a **num**ber or an **ast**erisk". But you shouldn't try to encode the type in the variable name. Just use `a` and `b` here.

What does `decodes_dp` mean? I would try to give it a better name. Use nouns for variables. Perhaps `number_of_possibilities`, or `num_decodings` (although that almost clashes with the function name).

## Use `std::array` for fixed-length vectors

This avoids unnecessary heap allocations. So:

```
std::array<uint64_t, 3> decodes_dp{1, decode(message[0]), 0};
```

## Remove unnecessary modulo operations

In the following expression:

```
decodes_dp[index % 3] = (
        decodes_dp[(index - 1) % 3] * decode(message[index - 1]) % MOD +
        decodes_dp[(index - 2) % 3] * decode(message[index - 2], message[index - 1]) % MOD
    ) % MOD;
```

Since you already need to use `uint64_t` for the result of the multiplications to not wrap, you don't need the modulo operations inside the outermost parentheses.

## Consider using `switch`-statements

Your `decode()` functions can be rewritten as follows:

```
inline uint64_t Solution::decode(const char a) {
    switch(a) {
        case '0':
            return 0;
        case '*':
            return 9;
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}

inline uint64_t Solution::decode(const char a, const char b) {
    switch(a) {
        case '0':
            return 0;
        case '1':
            return b == '*' ? 9 : 1;
        case '2':
            switch(b) {
                case '0'...'6':
                    return 1;
                case '*':
                    return 6;
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        case '*':
            return decode('1', b) + decode('2', b);
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

It's more compact and avoids repeating a lot of `if (a_num_ast ...)`, making it easier to see the structure of your code.

Comment: Single-letter variable names are fine in some cases. For example, `i`, `j` and `k` for loop indices, `x`, `y` and `z` for coordinates, and even `a` and `b` when you have some generic inputs for which there really is no more descriptive name. Those are commonly used, so they should not be surprising to others reading your code.